# "dbt deps" from local repository

Tags: dbt

Is it allowed to create local dbt deps repository so that "dbt deps" command should download libraries from local repository?

```
N.B: Our client is not interested to connect to external network.
```

Comment: can you please share what version of dbt you are using as well as which adapter you are using?

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is possible, provided that the repositories have already been locally cloned or copied.

[dbt docs's page on Packages](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management#local-packages) tells you exactly how to do this

> Packages that you have stored locally can be installed by specifying the path to the project, like so:
>
> ```yaml
> packages:
>   - local: /opt/dbt/redshift # use a local path
> ```
>
> Local packages should only be used for specific situations, for example, when testing local changes to a package.

Note: I think it is worth re-iterating the caveat given in the docs. You will now own downloading the cloning the correct versions of the packages along with the ongoing work of keeping the packages up-to-date.

As for how this works in practice. Consider the following example:

- `/Users/michelle/repos/my_dbt_project` where my dbt project lives (that contains `dbt_project.yml` and `packages.yml`
- `/Users/michelle/repos/dbt_utils` the location where I previously cloned the [dbt-utils](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils) repo

In this example my `packages.yml` should look like

```yaml
packages:
  - local: /Users/michelle/repos/dbt_utils # use a local path
```

Please note that the external package does not live within my dbt project directory, but outside of it. While it should work to have it within the repo, this is not best practice. This [external package development](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/contributing-to-an-external-dbt-package/657) article goes even further in-depth.

Comment: Hi @Andres, Really thanks for replying here. I tried the same way to it is mentioned in the URL. After mentioning the local path in package.yml file(as below) and copying the library package in a specific folder, dbt is not able to find the dbt_project.yml file whereas the dbt_project.yml is in the same folder where packages.yml file is existing. the packages:
  - package: data-mie/dbt_profiler
    version: 0.1.6
  - local: /Users/prakashdutta

Comment: just responded in the comment

Comment: Thanks @Andres. It's work fine now.

Comment: great do me a favor and accpet the answer!